Middleware Fiber stopped working correctly after connecting logrus
I'm working on logging for a simple server. I have enjoyed using fiber middleware. It logs requests beautifully. Then the need to log code came up, so I hooked up logrus. But now my fiber logger only logs requests that are linked to some other middleware, like favico or metrics. The rest of the requests are as if it doesn't see them. The order of connection middlewares has no effect.
app.Use(logger.New(logger.Config{
        Format: "[${ip}]:${port} ${status} - ${method} ${path}\n",
    }))

var Logger *logrus.Logger

type CustomFormatter struct {
    TimestampFormat string
}

func (f *CustomFormatter) Format(entry *logrus.Entry) ([]byte, error) {
    // Настройка цвета в зависимости от уровня логирования
    var levelColor int
    switch entry.Level {
    case logrus.DebugLevel, logrus.TraceLevel:
        levelColor = 36 // Cyan
    case logrus.WarnLevel:
        levelColor = 33 // Yellow
    case logrus.ErrorLevel, logrus.FatalLevel, logrus.PanicLevel:
        levelColor = 31 // Red
    default:
        levelColor = 32 // Green
    }

    timestamp := entry.Time.Format(f.TimestampFormat)


    fileName := filepath.Base(entry.Caller.File)
    line := entry.Caller.Line


    level := strings.ToUpper(entry.Level.String())


    log := fmt.Sprintf("%s \x1b[%dm[%s]\x1b[0m [%s:%d]  %s\n", timestamp, levelColor, level, fileName, line, entry.Message)

    return []byte(log), nil
}

type LogEntry struct {
    Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
    Level     string `json:"level"`
    File      string `json:"file"`
    Line      int    `json:"line"`
    Message   string `json:"message"`
}

type JSONFormatter struct{}

func (f *JSONFormatter) Format(entry *logrus.Entry) ([]byte, error) {
    logEntry := LogEntry{
        Timestamp: entry.Time.Format(time.RFC3339),
        Level:     entry.Level.String(),
        File:      filepath.Base(entry.Caller.File),
        Line:      entry.Caller.Line,
        Message:   entry.Message,
    }

    return json.Marshal(logEntry)
}

type LoggerHook struct {
    Writer    io.Writer
    Formatter logrus.Formatter
}

func (h *LoggerHook) Levels() []logrus.Level {
    return logrus.AllLevels
}

func (h *LoggerHook) Fire(entry *logrus.Entry) error {
    data, err := h.Formatter.Format(entry)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = h.Writer.Write(data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = h.Writer.Write([]byte("\n")) // Добавляем перевод строки после каждой записи
    return err
}

func SetupLogger(lv int, path string) *logrus.Logger {
    logger := logrus.New()


    logFile, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatalf("Failed to open log file: %v", err)
    }

    consoleFormatter := &CustomFormatter{
        TimestampFormat: "02-Jan-2006 15:04:05",
    }


    logger.SetOutput(io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout))
    logger.SetFormatter(consoleFormatter)

    logger.SetReportCaller(true)


    logger.AddHook(&LoggerHook{
        Writer:    logFile,
        Formatter: &JSONFormatter{},
    })

    logger.SetLevel(MapIntToLogLevel(lv))

    return logger
}


func MapIntToLogLevel(level int) logrus.Level {
    switch level {
    case 6:
        return logrus.PanicLevel
    case 5:
        return logrus.FatalLevel
    case 4:
        return logrus.ErrorLevel
    case 3:
        return logrus.WarnLevel
    case 2:
        return logrus.InfoLevel
    case 1:
        return logrus.DebugLevel
    case 0:
        return logrus.TraceLevel
    default:
        return logrus.InfoLevel 
    }
}

For example. Went to the page, sent a username and password. Went to the metrics page.
[127.0.0.1]:49775 200 - GET /metrics
[127.0.0.1]:49775 200 - GET /metrics
[127.0.0.1]:49775 200 - GET /favicon.ico
[127.0.0.1]:49775 200 - GET /metrics

Changed the order in which the middlewares were connected.
Output logs of the logger to a file.
Disconnected other middlewares.
I expected two loggers to work together, but the fiber logger refuses to work correctly.

You probably should ask the author of fiber: Fiber is a very opinionated framework.
